# AS400 RPG Program not returning anything

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange

I have the following code. The program just exits, no value returned from call. Any ideas?

```
AS400System system = new AS400System();
system.Define(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AS400Server"]);
system.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AS400User"];
system.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AS400Password"];
system.IPAddress = "10.98.1.21";
system.Connect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd);



if(system.IsConnected(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd) == 1) {
    Program program = new Program();
    program.LibraryName = "P2PTST";
    program.ProgramName = "AUI0XFR";
    program.system = system;
    program.system.Signon();

    string paramStatus = "A";
    Int64 paramStockItem = Int64.Parse(t.EtagNumber);
    Guid paramGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    string paramReturn;

    StringConverter stringConverter = new StringConverter();
    ProgramParameters parameters = new ProgramParameters();
    parameters.Append("ApiIGuid", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInout, 38);
    parameters.Append("StockItemNumber", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInout, 20);
    parameters.Append("ItemStatus", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInout, 1);
    parameters.Append("ReturnCode", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInout, 7);

    parameters["ApiIGuid"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(paramGuid.ToString().PadRight(38, ' '));
    parameters["StockItemNumber"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(paramStockItem.ToString().PadRight(20, ' '));
    parameters["ItemStatus"].Value = stringConverter.ToBytes(paramStatus.ToString());

    try{
        program.Call(parameters);
        paramReturn = stringConverter.FromBytes(parameters["ReturnCode"].Value);

        system.Disconnect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceAll);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the IBM i side to see what is happening there?

Comment: There's no ELSE for system.isConnected.  Are you certain you've connected?

Answer (score 0):

We just went through this and had the same issues, so decided to create and use a stored procedure to accomplish this in .NET.  Because we were concerned about having the 400 side distribute the code to create a stored procedure, it ended up being very quick to go ahead and create the procedure on the PC side, followed by our remote command, so no additional changes were necessary on the 400 side.

My environment is Win7 x64 running VS2012 C#, CAX V7.1, and importing both IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, and System.Data;

I need System.Data for the Parameters. That ended up being critical to get data back!

I send the 400 two params, filesetID and a name.  I get back a number and a uuid.
(but they are all characters!)

It looks something like this:

```
    public void RemoteCmd(ref PicMeta pm)
    {
    iDB2Connection cn;
        try
        {
            using (cn = new iDB2Connection("DataSource=<servername/IP>; UserID="<user>"; Password="<pass>";"))
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (iDB2Command cm = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    //Place a try/catch here, so it will create the procedure the first time, or any time it has been removed from the 400.  If already set, it will fail, and you'll go directly to the remote command.  
                    try
                    {
                         //Here we create a procedure and execute or continue.
                         cm.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE LIBRARY.SP_PICGETID(INOUT FSET CHAR (1 ), INOUT UNIT CHAR (6 ), INOUT NEXTID CHAR (3 ), INOUT UUID CHAR (36 ))  LANGUAGE RPGLE NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL CALLED ON NULL INPUT EXTERNAL NAME LIBRARY.PICGETID PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL";
                         cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                    //Continue - create and call the command     
                    //ParameterDirection needs "using System.Data;"
                    cm.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cm.CommandText = "LIBRARY.SP_PICGETID";

                    iDB2Parameter p = new iDB2Parameter();
                    p.ParameterName = "FSET";
                    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    p.iDB2DbType = iDB2DbType.iDB2Char;
                    p.Size = 1;
                    p.iDB2Value = pm.fileset;
                    cm.Parameters.Add(p);

                    p = new iDB2Parameter();
                    p.ParameterName = "UNIT";
                    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    p.iDB2DbType = iDB2DbType.iDB2Char;
                    p.Size = 6;
                    p.iDB2Value = pm.unit;
                    cm.Parameters.Add(p);

                    p = new iDB2Parameter();
                    p.ParameterName = "NEXTID";
                    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
                    p.iDB2DbType = iDB2DbType.iDB2Char;
                    p.Size = 3;
                    p.iDB2Value = "";
                    cm.Parameters.Add(p);

                    p = new iDB2Parameter();
                    p.ParameterName = "GUUID";
                    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
                    p.iDB2DbType = iDB2DbType.iDB2Char;
                    p.Size = 36;
                    p.iDB2Value = "";
                    cm.Parameters.Add(p);

                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    iDB2ParameterCollection pc = cm.Parameters;

                    //We get our Out parameters here 
                    pm.nextid = pc["NEXTID"].Value.ToString();
                    pm.uuid = pc["GUUID"].Value.ToString();
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Hope this helps!